# Why is viewport scene violet?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, shaders, world

I've switched from C4D (getting too costly for a retiree) to Blender 2.8. I've created a simple scene consisting of the monkey atop a plane.  Why is everything in the viewport and eevee shaded in violet (see attached screenprint)?

[image: 1]

Comment: You say "see attached screenprint", but there is no image attached.

Comment: this is not a duplicate to, "Why are all the textures in my file pink?."  That is not the problem he is having.

Comment: Would you mid [sharing your .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we can see what's going on?

Comment: @Millard Could be if the environment texture isn't loaded.

Comment: I think your right, rjg, I didn't think of that,  @Dan Kuras, is there an environment texture?

Comment: I didn't know I had to use on.  It now works correctly.  Thanks